# User defined linked list returning pointer from function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, linked-list

I know i asked a similar question a while back but its still not working. Sorry for repetition i am just not sure why it does not work. I created my own linked list(not using the stl library) I have my classes set up and work perfectly how I want them too. The problem I have is getting a reference back when I use a function to populate the list. 
in my main I call the function `bookSetUp()` which is used to populate the list. I make the this function equal to a temp pointer. (Heres the code)
**Main.cpp**

```
Book* temp = bookSetUp();
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    cout<<temp->getName()<<endl;
    cout<<temp->getAuthor()<<endl;
    cout<<temp->getISBN()<<endl;
    temp = temp->getNext();
}
```

bookSetUp() is located in another .cpp file called **functions.cpp**(Links are working between the two .cpp's as i have tested them)
**functions.cpp**
     `Book* bookSetUp()

    {`

```
//The items that populate the list
Book a("A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", 1203456, true);
Book b("Lord of the rings", "J.R.R Tolkein", 123456, true);
Book c("Le Petit Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", 123457, true);
Book d("And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", 123458, true);
Book e("Dream of the Red Chamber","Cao Xueqin",123459, true);
Book f("The Hobbit","J.R.R Tolkein",123467, true);

a.setPrev(NULL);
a.setNext(&b);
b.setPrev(&a);
b.setNext(&c);
c.setPrev(&b);
c.setNext(&d);
d.setPrev(&c);
d.setNext(&e);
e.setPrev(&d);
e.setNext(&f);
f.setPrev(&e);
f.setNext(NULL);

Book* temp = &a;
return temp;

}
```

As you can see i am trying to return a pointer to the first item on the list so that main has access to it. My book class has attributes: string name,string author,int isbn and bool availability.
The program crashes with **"Unhandled exception at 0x00B16886 in bookRepository.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCD04."** which im guessing means it is not getting a value back from the bookSetUp() function.
Also in the debugger the int ISBN returns but not the string(s) or bool.
Does anyone know why this is not working? it would be a massive help if you could!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very common misunderstanding by newbies who don't really understand how pointers should be used.

One step at a time.

1. In bookSetup you create 6 Book objects.
2. You set various pointers, in particular you set `temp` to the address of the `a`
   Book.
3. You exit the function bookSetup.
4. **At this point all the Book objects are destroyed!**
5. So you have returned from bookSetup with a pointer to an object which has been destroyed.
6. As a consequence when you try to use that pointer your program crashes.

This method cannot work. You need to learn about another technique called 'dynamic allocation'. This uses `new` to create Books. Dynamically created objects are not destroyed automatically, so for a linked list you really need to use dynamic allocation.

E.g.

```
Book* a = new Book("A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", 1203456, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the newbie :P 
would I have to populate a booklist in the main then? or is there a way around this?? @john

Comment: @Dennington-bear Just updated with the way around this. In short use `new`.

Comment: Ya I have seen dynamic allocation before so its grand just did not realise they were being destroyed at the functions end. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes i can tell.

in c++ , objects are saved in the Heap . when the function is getting out of scope the variables that was saved in the heap are released(deleted).

the problem in your program is :

your bookSetup function is creating objects on the heap
then it return the reference(address in memory) to those objects. but when the function ends all the objects in the heap are deleted. therefore you return an address that point to nothing.

in order to fix this problem you need to save these objects in the stack instead of the heap.

to do that you use the keyword "new" (the "new" keyword allocating space on the stack)

if i remember this is the syntax:

```
Book* a = new Book("A Tale of Two Cities", "Charles Dickens", 1203456, true);
Book* b= new Book("Lord of the rings", "J.R.R Tolkein", 123456, true);
Book* c= new Book("Le Petit Prince", "Antoine de Saint-Exupéry", 123457, true);
Book* d= new Book("And Then There Were None", "Agatha Christie", 123458, true);
Book* e= new Book("Dream of the Red Chamber","Cao Xueqin",123459, true);
Book* f= new Book("The Hobbit","J.R.R Tolkein",123467, true);
```

Comment: That should be `Book* a = new Book(...);`

Comment: You seem to confuse 'heap' and `stack` in your answer. Please fix that!